# PHP w/ PDO: Create variable number of class fields on the fly and execute them in a single transaction

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, pdo

I'll do my best to describe the problem in details so you can provide a good answer and reward you by accepting it.

My class BaseEntry and its BaseEntryMapper are responsible for managing the basic details of a business directory entry (let's stick just to "phone, fax, cell").

Classes BaseEntryMeta and BaseEntryMetaMapper should deal with any additional inputs from a user (phone_2, phone_3, ..., fax_2, fax_3, ..., cell_2, .... but also many other features!) he may or may not make.

While the baseEntry (+Mapper) class work fine and save OK, I'm having issues making the other one to work. That is due to the fact I cannot know how many additional features a user may leave. I know I can create those on the fly so I intend to use the names of my form's input fields to set them with a loop like so:

```
$baseEntryMeta->$formFieldName = $_POST['formFieldName']
```

For the basic part, I call the saveBaseEntry method like this (note how an object is being passed):

```
$baseEntry = new BaseEntry();
$baseEntryMapper = new BaseEntryMapper($pdo);
$baseEntryMapper->saveBaseEntry($baseEntry);
```

Now the other class (additional inputs / features of an entry). I tried passing an object too, but it won't work. I decided to collect all the info into an array and pass that array instead of an object (I adjusted the method to expect an array):

```
$metaData = array(
    array(
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_key = "phone_2",
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_value = "999 555 2222",
    ),
    array(
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_key = "phone_3",
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_value = "999 555 6666",
    ),
    array(
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_key = "fax_2",
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_value = "999 555 2222",
    ),
    array(
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_key = "cell_2",
        $baseEntryMeta->meta_value = "999 444 3333",
    )
);    

$baseEntryMeta = new BaseEntryMeta();
$baseEntryMetaMapper = new BaseEntryMetaMapper($pdo);

$baseEntryMetaMapper->saveBaseEntryMeta($metaData);
```

Now my saveBaseEntryMeta() method:

```
public function saveEntryMeta(array $data)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$this->table." (entry_id, meta_key, meta_value) 
        VALUES (:entry_id, :meta_key, :meta_value)
    ";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam("entry_id", $entryMeta->entry_id);
    // the above param wasn't mentioned, but it is needed in the code
    $stmt->bindParam("meta_key", $entryMeta->meta_key);
    $stmt->bindParam("meta_value", $entryMeta->meta_value);
    $stmt->execute($data);
}
```

Some questions:
1. Is the array that is passed structured in a way that is acceptable by the PDO?
2. I think I read somewhere this part (after VALUES):

(:entry_id, :meta_key, :meta_value)

should be duplicated for each array element (through a loop).
3. If the above is correct, what should I pass to the execute statement so that info is saved as separate rows?
4. Could all saving be done in a single transaction?

Thank you!

See my other questions related to this project (I found some solutions myself but I'm willing to hear new suggestions and accept good answers) - they may provide more details on issues I'm having on the project.

EDIT: I moved my previous edit(s) into a separate answer so i can later accept it for anyone else who might have the same problem in the future.

Comment: I would suggest you figure out the schema of database first.

Comment: I actually have db schema in place. AND I made it work but need some further advice. Please read the edit in my 1st post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by structuring my array like this:

```
$metaData = array(
    0 => array( "entry_id" => $entry->id ),
    1 => array(
        0 => array(
            "meta_key" => "phone_2",
            "meta_value" => "el-0 555 87878"
        ),
        1 => array(
            "meta_key" => "phone_3",
            "meta_value" => "el-1 555 87878"
        ),
        2 => array(
            "meta_key" => "fax_2",
            "meta_value" => "el-2 222 87878"
        ),
        3 => array(
            "meta_key" => "cell_2",
            "meta_value" => "el-3 111 87878"
        ),
        4 => array(
            "meta_key" => "cell_3",
            "meta_value" => "el-4 777 87878"
        )
    )
);
```

and my save method like this:

```
public function saveEntryMeta(array $data)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$this->table} (entry_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(1, $entry_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(2, $meta_key);
    $stmt->bindParam(3, $meta_value);

    for($i=0; $i<count($data[1]); $i++){
        $entry_id = $data[0]["entry_id"];
        $meta_key = $data[1][$i]["meta_key"];
        $meta_value = $data[1][$i]["meta_value"];
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

It saves to my db table like this:

```
entry_id    meta_key    meta_value
 66         phone_2      555 777 8888
 66         phone_3      555 777 9999
 66         cell_2       555 1111 8888
```